# ERC 721 card game

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, dapp-development, erc-721

The general concept of ERC 721 is clear to me. My question is more about the contract deployment. I want to have 100 unique cards, So I thought of these two implementations:

1. Having an initial supply(mint) of 100 so there will be 100 unique cards.
2. Deploying 100 different contracts.

I think the 1st method is better, But I din't know whether it is right. Opinions/feedbacks are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An NFT contract is meant to hold one type of NFT tokens - in your example cards. It has information about who owns which unique card. So it would not make sense to deploy own contract for each card - they would be separate NFTs and they would not be interchangeable/transferable so easily. If they are all in the same contract they belong to the same "group" and have the same specifications.. And of course deploying a new almost-the-same contract over and over again would cost a lot of gas and sounds silly.

Therefore you should either create all the needed cards already in the constructor or then in separate transaction(s) mint the required cards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes sense to go with option 1